# Failed Windows Update : Windows 10 Fall Creators Upate 1709

Tags: windows-10

I ran the troubleshooter as the administrator but have two issues that weren't solved and I'm not sure how to fix them. The two issues are:
Potential Window Update Database error detected and Check for pending updates. Please advise the simplest way to fix these issues. Thanks

Comment: Search for these steps: 1. disable windows update services from my computer - manager - services. 2. Delete windows\softwaredistribution folder. 3. re-enable the windows update services (there can be more than one service related to update)

Comment: which error code do you get? look in settings app-Windows update->history for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Method 1:**

Run Windows Updater troubleshooter:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4027322/windows-windows-update-troubleshooter

**Method 2:**

1.Open an elevated command prompt

2.Type and run the following command:

Sfc /scannow

Dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

3. Then check if the issue still persists

**Method 3:**

1.Open an elevated command prompt

2.Run the following command:

net stop bits

net stop wuauserv

net stop appidsvc

net stop cryptsvc

ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old

ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 catroot2.old

net start bits

net start wuauserv

net start appidsvc

net start cryptsvc

3. Exit command prompt and check if the issue persists

And please also run the following command as Admin to clear pending update:

dism.exe /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions